# Runtime error is coming while solving the question

Tags: java

187. Repeated DNA Sequences
     https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-dna-sequences/

I am solving this question on Leetcode and I am stuck on some silly error.Please, help me out.

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> findRepeatedDnaSequences(String s) {
       Set<String> seen=new HashSet();
        Set<String> repeated=new HashSet();
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=10;
        while(j<s.length()){
            if(j-i+1<k)j++;
            if(j-i+1==k){
               String substr=s.substring(i,j+1);
               if(seen.contains(substr)){
                 repeated.add(substr);
                 }
                 else{
                 seen.add(substr);
              }
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        
        return new ArrayList(repeated);
    }
}
```

It's giving me runtime error-

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 10, length 9
  at line 4601, java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd
  at line 2704, java.base/java.lang.String.substring
  at line 38, Solution.findRepeatedDnaSequences
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

Comment: Why do you use +1 in both your `if` statements and in your substring `s.substring(i,j+1);`. The error is caused by trying to create a substring that is 1 character longer that your actual string. Remember that indexes start at 0, so when you have 10 characters, the actual range is 0 to 9, not 1 to 10.

Comment: @sorifiend can you plz update the code by what you are saying. Also, I have every substring that takes 10 chars so it starts from i=0 to j=9+1=10 and takes 9 chars.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this line `if(j-i+1<k)j++;`

Consider the following code:

```
int j=0;
int k=10;
while(j<s.length()){
    if(j-i+1<k)
        j++;
```

The above code will always cause the value of `j` inside your while loop to increment and start at 1 (not 0) which will cause your substring to overflow by 1 at the other end as well. We can fix this by simply moving the line `if(j-i+1<k)j++;` to be lower down in your code. But also, we know `j` has to be incrimented every loop, so there in no point even using `if(j-i+1<k)`:

```
while(j<s.length()){
    if(j-i+1==k){
        String substr=s.substring(i,j+1);
        if(seen.contains(substr)){
             repeated.add(substr);
         }
         else{
             seen.add(substr);
        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
//Incriment j here after checking the sequence
    j++;
}
return new ArrayList(repeated);
```

The next issue is that you were attempting to increment `j++;` inside both of your `if` statement which will only cause your code to skip values, to fix this simply remove `j++;` from your other `if` statement like so:

```
while(j<s.length()){
    if(j-i+1==k){
        String substr=s.substring(i,j+1);
        if(seen.contains(substr)){
             repeated.add(substr);
         }
         else{
             seen.add(substr);
        }
        i++;
//Delete the following line
        //j++;
    }
//Incriment j here after checking the sequence
    j++;
}
return new ArrayList(repeated);
```

Now your method will correctly return the duplicate sequences without an out of bounds exception.

Note that you can make your code even more readable and simpler by getting rid of the `i` variable, and editing your while loop to do the work for you `while (j <= s.length()-k){`, note the `<=` and `-k` at the end that ensures we do not get any out of bounds exceptions by finishing the loop 10 characters before the end:

```
int j = 0;
int k = 10;
//find every possible sequence that is at least 10 characters long using "j <= s.length()-k"
while (j <= s.length()-k){
    String substr = s.substring(j, j + k);
    if (seen.contains(substr)){
        repeated.add(substr);
    }
    else{
        seen.add(substr);
    }
    j++;
}
return new ArrayList(repeated);
```